# Shared preferences for email

Tags: android

This is supposed to save the users email as a shared preference, but when I run it it only shows the default "Email Address" saved and not their saved input

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText email;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lab_3);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        loadSavedPreferences();
    }

    public void save(View view) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences("email", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString("storedEmail", email.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();
    }

    private void loadSavedPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences("sharedPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String tempEmail = sharedPref.getString("storedEmail", "Email Address");
        email.setText(tempEmail);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `loadSavedPreferences()` method, you use different preference name (`sharedPref`). So, you can modify `loadSavedPreferences`:

```
private void loadSavedPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences("email", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String tempEmail = sharedPref.getString("email", "Email Address");
    email.setText(tempEmail);

}
```